# Theano Lock Issue for pymc3 with Python 3.8 and macOS15 (Catalina)

Tags: python, pymc3

Recently, I upgraded macOS to macOS15 (Catalina) with the latest Anaconda Navigator (with Python 3.8).  When I run pymc3, I encountered:

```
INFO (theano.gof.compilelock): Waiting for existing lock by process '38830' (I am process '40110')
INFO (theano.gof.compilelock): To manually release the lock, delete /Users/STsutsui/.theano/compiledir_macOS-10.15.6-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.8.3-64/lock_dir
```

Since I am not familiar with UNIX, I do not know what to do.  Any help is welcome.

Thank you in advance.

STsutsui

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this problem by defining your own compile directory. This can be done using the `AESARA_FLAG` environmental variable like so:

`export AESARA_FLAGS="base_compiledir=${tmpdir}/.aesara"`

That directory must of course exist (so run something like `mkdir -p ${tmpdir}/.aesara` first). And you should tidy up after yourself, so if running in a bash script you should put this near the top:

```bash
function cleanup {
    rm -R $tmpdir
}

trap cleanup EXIT
```